# python pandas: add several columns to a DF based on applying func to index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, apply

I would like to add columns to a dataframe based on the index, which is of a string type.

Provided I have a df as follows:

```
# Creating the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['10/2/2011', '11/2/2011', '12/2/2011', '13/2/2011'],
                    'Event':['Music', 'Poetry', 'Theatre', 'Comedy'],
                    'Cost':[10000, 5000, 15000, 2000]}, index=['john','mike','alfred','jerry'])
 
# Print the dataframe
print(df)
```

I would like to add several columns based on a class that makes some calculations. As example I created here a straight forward on:

```
class telbook():
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {'john':'python','mike':'C','alfred':'excel','jerry':'python'}
        self.country = {'john':'spain','mike':'India','alfred':'germany','jerry':'themoon'}
book= telbook()    
book.data['john']
```

The following does not work:

```
df['lang'] = pd.Series(df.index).apply(lambda user_name: book.data[user_name])
df['country'] = pd.Series(df.index).apply(lambda user_name: book.country[user_name])
```

does not give an error but adds a column of NANs

the questions are:
first: how should I proceed?
second: assuming that I want to extract a bunch of properties of this telbook class for every employee, is there any more convenient method to add multiple columns in one go?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html) directly on the index after instantiating your class:

```
class telbook():
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {'john':'python','mike':'C','alfred':'excel','jerry':'python'}
        self.country = {'john':'spain','mike':'India','alfred':'germany','jerry':'themoon'}


tb = telbook()

df['lang'] = df.index.map(tb.data)
df['country'] = df.index.map(tb.country)

print(df)
```

output:

```
             Date    Event   Cost    lang  country
john    10/2/2011    Music  10000  python    spain
mike    11/2/2011   Poetry   5000       C    India
alfred  12/2/2011  Theatre  15000   excel  germany
jerry   13/2/2011   Comedy   2000  python  themoon
```